# Fillomino with Sums: The Fillo That Smiles Back!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This puzzle is a [Fillomino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fillomino), with the special variant rule of Sums ("Cages") being applied. You might also notice that this particular fillomino is giving you a smile! This is my first time making a Fillomino, especially one with variant rules, so I hope you enjoy.

**Standard Fillomino rules:** *(paraphrased from Melon's Puzzle Pack Volume IV)*

> In Fillomino, the goal is to **divide all of the grid squares into polyominoes**, subject to
> the following constraints:
>
> 1. Every number in the grid must be contained in a polyomino containing that
>    quantity of squares.
> 2. No two polyominoes containing the same quantity of squares may share an edge.
> 3. A polyomino may contain one, more than one, or none of the numbers originally
>    given.

**Sum rule variant:** *(paraphrased from Melon's Puzzle Pack Volume IV)*

> Sum: In addition to the usual rules, the grid contains some cages. **The number at the
> top left of each cage gives the sum of all numbers that appear inside of it**. Numbers
> may be repeated in cages.

Now, here is the puzzle:

[image]

[And here is a Penpa link](https://git.io/JtP7x) to solve it in your browser, if you'd like. *(Quick Penpa tip if you haven't used it before: Placing numbers uses "Mode -> Number", and placing walls uses "Mode -> Edge.")*

Comment: was the title inspired by goldfish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the basic deductions from extending regions:

> [image]

Next, look at some sum cages.

> The very lower right cell must not be alone, so it must be connected to the cell above it. That makes that number 3.
>
>  Similarly, the very lower left *cannot* be a 3, because it would run into the 3s above it. It also can't be a 5, because then the other cell in the pair would be a 1. That means the lower left cell must be a 1.
>
>  [image]

Next, the upper left:

> The 9 group in column 3 doesn't have enough room in the upper left. So it must join up with the 9 group on top, through the cell R2C4.
>
>  This lets us resolve the upper left area entirely.
>
>  [image]

...And from here, I believe there are **multiple solutions**.

Unless I've made a mistake (which very well could be the case), this demonstrates at least two solutions to the puzzle. (I've highlighted 1s, 2s, and 3s for easier checking.)

> [image]

Comment: Oh no!! I test-solved so many times and was sure there was only one solution, but it looks like I didn't test-solve enough.... completely my bad for not solve-pathing thoroughly :( will accept this answer since it was the first, of course.

Comment: Deus sniped, as usual, I was trying it out, and ran into a rabbit hole of contradictions :( +1!